# Hibernate + Clases Abstractas

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Siguiendo en cuanto a mis dudas de Hibernate se refiere.
Digamos que tengo una base de datos con la tabla `asignatura`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `asignatura` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Esta clase en Java seria abstracta:

```
public abstract class Asignatura{

}
```

Ya que de esta derivarian por ejemplo, Matemáticas, Química...

```
public class Matematicas extends Asignatura{

}
```

Mi duda es, ¿cómo hago para guardar los objetos de `Matematicas` en la tabla `Asignaturas`, es automatico? o hay que hacer algo especial?

Comment: Matemáticas sería un registro, para que necesitarías convertir un registro en una clase? si pones un ejemplo de uso o más detalaldo será más fácil ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un concepto equivocado sobre lo que es guardar (persistir) objetos de una entidad JPA en la base de datos. Siguiendo el hilo de la estructura que deseas crear...

`Asignatura` debe ser una clase concreta, no abstracta.

Y "Matemáticas" sería un objeto de esa clase, que al persistirlo en la base de datos, sería un nuevo registro en la tabla Asignatura.

La clase de entidad debería ser algo como:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "asignatura")
public class Asignatura{
@Id
private int id;
@Column
private String name;
//getters/setters...
}
```

Y crear una asignatura llamada "Matemáticas" sería de la siguiente manera:

```
Asignatura nuevaAsignatura = new Asignatura();
nuevaAsignatura.setId(123);
nuevaAsignatura.setNombre("Matemáticas");
```

Para persistir este objeto en la base de datos, se debe usar el método `persist()` del entityManager.

```
entityManager.persist(nuevaAsignatura);
```

Generaría internamente el siguiente código SQL:

```
INSERT INTO asignatura (id, name)
VALUES (123, 'Matemáticas');
```

Insertando un nuevo registro en la tabla Asignatura.

```
      asignatura
----------------------
| id  |     name     |
----------------------
| 123 |  Matemáticas |
```